# Why am I being charged for 7-day PITR?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm running a BC 6-vcore Gen 5 single database with 1.5 TB of storage space.  My PITR configuration is set to 7 days.  I have been operating the server for 4 months.  Beginning Sep 25, I began getting charged for "SQL Database Single/Elastic Pool PITR Backup Storage - RA-GRS Data Stored".  I thought 7-day PITR was free according to the Microsoft documentation.  I am trying to figure out how to stop these charges but have not found a solution.

Any thoughts?  Am I missing something in the fine print?

Comment: There was a new backup storage charge introduced on 1st Nov. Anything storage over 1.5TB (your current size) is charged. What's your backup storage size? I don't know but if you have a lot of changes, it will be a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nick.  I didn't realize there was a 1.5 TB limit.  Do you know if there is any Microsoft documentation about this?  I've searched all over without finding anything.  I should have also mentioned in my post that we have the entire 1.5 TB of space allocated but are only utilizing 1 TB.  Do you think deallocating the extra 0.5 TB makes a difference or would we need to reduce the max size of the database?  Thanks!

Comment: It’s in the doco. 100% of your database size is free for backup. It’s not 1.5 Tb it’s whatever size your dB is at.

Comment: @demarius12 Our hosting cost are going increase by 156.25% that's right it is going to be about about an extra 24K per month just like that. Microsoft has not been able to provide any solutions to this problem and I am in an arms race to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favourite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745).

Answer (score 2):

From the docs at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/pricing/details/sql-database/single/

> The backup cost depends on the size of the database, the rate of
>   change and the configured retention period. The storage amount up to
>   100 percent of database size is provided at no extra charge.
>   Additional backup storage consumption will be charged in GB/month

Actual backup storage required is difficult to estimate, but if you have a lot of change going on, the TL backups wll be bigger and that's more storage.

Throwing around some rought numbers;

If you have 1Gb of changes to your DB per day, it needs to store 7 days of changes (7 x 1Gb) + various other backups (probably at least one full backup plus a differential.

Because your DB is currently 1.5G, you get the first 1.5G free so you have to pay the balance of 5.5G

I'm not completely across the modelling and calculations and I'm not sure how they roll that up to a month, but that's what I get from the doco.

There was also a note saying it starts 1st November but I can't find that now.

Comment: Thanks for the numbers Nick.  We currently have 100% of 1.5 TB allocated but are only using around 900 GB (we accidentally created a massive table and then deleted it).  Do you think shrinking the database so that there is around 600 GB of unallocated space would save us on PITR costs? (I am inexperienced and really new to all of this so thanks for all the help!)

Comment: Basically you would not save any money on backups, only on database storagem and 300GB is probably $100USD a month. Full backups only backup your used space _and_ they would be compressed. A big cost saver would actually be going from business critical to general purpose, but it depends on your usage and requirements

Comment: Interesting thanks for the info Nick.  Right now our PITR costs are going to exceed 2k at the end of this month so I'm just trying to understand how we are so getting hit by this so badly considering 10 days ago we never even once encountered this charge.  Is there anyway to track how the differential changes are calculated?

Comment: We're well into conjecture territory here now. Here's more detail that my colleague posted https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e92f8dbe-6296-4263-af2b-4aa1b96b6e6b/sql-managed-instance-pitr-backup-costs-september-1-2019-help-me-understand-the-architecture?forum=ssdsgetstarted&prof=required I couldn't find any refererence to identifying the size or type of backup files created by this process. However the best thing I got out of that post is _Any billing related issues you experience can be addressed through opening a billing related support request. No support plan required._

Comment: The best thing to do would be open a free billing enquiry. However it doesn't seem that there is anything you can change about your steup to save money. Except ironically you could move to an IaaS solution (SQL Server installed on an Azure VM)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=sql-database) official pricing calculator you have to pay $150 per month for backup storage (PITR) of 1.5 TB;

Comment: Thanks for posting that Alberto but unfortunately our PITR costs are much higher than that.  We are paying in the range of $50 per day right now in PITR costs alone which is accounting for nearly 40% of our total database costs.

Comment: @demarius12 we got royally screwed as well. I don't even see a way to turn off the PITR option to roll our own.